# Trying to use "pip install pandas" and receive the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to Python and have installed Python 3.8, PyCharm community edition and am trying to install pandas. The pandas module shows in in my available packages in PyCharm but when I try to install I receive the above error message.
If I try and run it from the CMD I receive the error: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. And if I try the same command in the Python shell I get an 'invalid syntax' error. I would uninstall everything and start fresh but the fact it's telling me there's "no module named Cython" is making me think something specific is wrong. 
 Anyone have a solution to this please?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you installed `pip`?

Comment: I'd read that the version of Python I downloaded should come with pip already installed; is the actual install something I need to do manually?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python for data science, I think you can make use of [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) package manager. It will install the most used libraries for you and provides a user interface for quickly installing and managing the others.

Comment: Yeah seeing similar posts that seems to be the most common answer, I'd still like to know how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

first check is pip installed on your system or not by typing following command:

By default pip file structure will be like

```
C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip --version
```

if it's not installed then download [download pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

Now navigate to following path and install pandas:

```
C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install pandas
```

Note: Make sure the path is right,while using above paths. according to your system configuration for pip  above path might be different.